# Sql Server Aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a select query as,

```
SELECT isnull(T1.TotalShows, 0) AS TotalShows, isnull(T1.ScreenCapacity, 0) AS ScreenCapacity, isnull(T1.ShowDate, 0) AS ShowDate, isnull(T2.TotalTicketsSold, 0) AS TotalTicketsSold, isnull(T2.Nett, 0) AS Nett
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(showtimeId) AS TotalShows, sum(sc.Capacity) AS ScreenCapacity, ShowDate 
    FROM Shows s
    JOIN Screens sc ON sc.ScreenID = s.ScreenID
    WHERE s.MovieID = 34
        AND s.IsDeleted = 0
    GROUP BY ShowDate
    ) AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT s.ShowDate, COUNT(ut.UserTicketID) AS TotalTicketsSold, SUM(ISNULL((Price + ConvinienceCharge - DiscountAmount) / (EntertainmentTax + BoxOfficeTax + 1), 0)) AS Nett
    FROM Shows s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTickets ut ON s.ShowID = ut.ShowID
    WHERE ut.ShowID IN (
            SELECT ShowID
            FROM Shows
            WHERE MovieID = 34
                AND IsDeleted = 0
            GROUP BY ShowID
            )
    GROUP BY s.ShowDate
    ) AS T2 ON T1.ShowDate = T2.ShowDate
```

This returns data as,
[image]

I want to aggregate data as

```
SUM(totalShows),SUM(ScreenCapacity),MAX(ShowDate),SUM(TotalTicketsSold),SUM(Nett)
```

But I want this only for first 7 rows as shown in above image. For more than 7 rows I want the aggregated data in the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, ShowDate), DATEPART(WEEK, ShowDate)
```

Comment: Really, it worked for exactly 7 rows. But, Would you mind telling for may be 10 or more rows?

Comment: I was under the assumption that you actually wanted to group by week. This gives you grouping by week regardless of whether or not all seven days of any given week are represented in the table. (i.e. if one date is missing, it will not just move along until it reaches seven, but that particular group will be the aggregate of six records). This is not to be construed as an arbitrary clumping function.

Comment: If you do want an arbitrary clumping function, you could perhaps do something with `row_number`, and grouping over the items that are divisible by the same arbitrary number. [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ecec3/17)